# LINQ to SQL - updating records

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

Using asp.net 4 though C#.

In my data access layer I have methods for saving and updating records. Saving is easy enough but the updating is tedious.

I previously used SubSonic which was great as it had active record and knew that if I loaded a record, changed a few entries and then saved it again, it recognised it as an update and didn't try to save a new entry in the DB.

I don't know how to do the same thing in LINQ. As a result my workflow is like this:

1. Web page grabs 'Record A' from the DB
2. Some values in it are changed by the user.
3. 'Record A' is passed back to the data access layer
4. I now need to load Record A again, calling it 'SavedRecord A', update all values in this object with the values from the passed 'Record A' and then update/ save 'SavedRecord A'!

If I just save 'Record A' I end up with a new entry in the DB.

Obviously it would be nicer to just pass Record A and do something like:

```
RecordA.Update();
```

I'm presuming there's something I'm missing here but I can't find a straightforward answer on-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When LINQ-to-SQL updates a record in the database, it needs to know exactly what fields were changed in order to only update those. You basically have three options:

- When the updated data is posted back to the web server, load the existing data from the database, assign all properties to the loaded object and call `SubmitChanges()`. Any properties that are assigned the existing value will not be updated.
- Keep track of the unmodified state of the object and use `Attach` with both the unmodified and modified values.
- Initialize a new object with all state required by the optimistic concurrency check (if enabled, which it is by default). Then attach the object and finally update any changed properties *after* the attach to make the DataContext change tracker be aware of those updated.

I usually use the first option as it is easiest. There is a performance penalty with two DB calls but unless you're doing lots of updates it won't matter.

Comment: Thanks, it's kind of surprising that there's no nicer way of doing it. I've been doing the 'two DB calls' method since starting to use LINQ to SQL but I've always had a nagging feeling I was missing an obviously easier answer. Looks like I haven't, which is both good and bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish what you want using the [`Attach` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978.aspx) on the `Table` instance, and committing via the `SubmitChanges()` method on the `DataContext`.

This process may not be as straight-forward as we would like, but you can read David DeWinter's [LINQ to SQL: Updating Entities](http://davedewinter.com/2009/04/07/linq-to-sql-updating-entities/) for a more in depth explanation/tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

let's say you have a product class OR DB, then you will have to do this.

```
    DbContext _db = new DbContext();

    var _product = ( from p in _db.Products
                                    where p.Id == 1  // suppose you getting the first product
                                    select p).First();  // this will fetch the first record.

     _product.ProductName = "New Product";

     _db.SaveChanges();

      // this is for EF LINQ to Objects
     _db.Entry(_product).State = EntityState.Modified;  
     _db.SaveChanges();

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is another example using Attach
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public static void Update(IEnumerable<Sample> samples , DataClassesDataContext db)
{
    db.Samples.AttachAll(samples);
    db.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, samples)
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

If you attach your entities to the context and then Refresh (with KeepCurrentValues selected), Linq to SQL will get those entities from the server, compare them, and mark updated those that are different

Comment: Thanks, in my case though I won't really know what fields have changed as the user will be doing the editing. Thus I have to assume all fields have changed and write the update accordingly. It's tedious but at least I know now I've been doing it the 'proper' way, even though it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: it doesnt matter what fields have been edited by the user, as long as you pass the model to the ActionResult in your controller in HTTPPOST method and call the SaveChanges(), the entire records gets updated in the DB.

Comment: So, is it possible to make this work where the client has only passed back a single changed value + a key reference field? Say you pass them a serialized record and they pass back an updated serialized record containing only the two fields. So far in my tests LinqToSql just tried to overwrite existing data with nulls. Obviously this means you would never be able to explicitly null a nullable field. Trying to have to avoid writing lots of thisfield = thatfield.